# Unknown error on chrome.tabs.executeScript

Tags: javascript, oauth, google-chrome-extension, dropbox-api

I need to run a script on an external page.

I'm trying to consume the Dropbox API (JavaScript and HTML only).
I'm using [JsOAuth](https://github.com/bytespider/jsOAuth) to work with OAuth.

### Code

This application is a pair of type [Packaged Apps](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/apps.html) to Google Chrome.

**Authorise**

```
//Request token
chrome.windows.create({url: url, type:"popup"}, function(win){
        chrome.tabs.executeScript(win.id, { file: "contentScript.js" }, function(){
            console.log("Callback executeScript!!");    
        });
    });
```

url = *Request token url*

[image: Dropbox OAuth]

**contentScript.js**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    console.log("Script injected!!!");
})
```

**Error in console**

> Error during tabs.executeScript: Unknown error.
>   chromeHidden.handleResponseextensions/schema_generated_bindings.js:94
>   openAuthoriseWindowscripts.js:297
>   g.fetchRequestTokenjsOAuth-1.3.3.min.js:1
>   g.init.request.q.onreadystatechange

### Attempts

As the external page can not jQuery, an effort was to remove the reference to jQuery

**contentScript.js**

```
console.log("Script injected!!!");
```

**Error in console**

```
Error during tabs.executeScript: Unknown error.
chromeHidden.handleResponse
```

Another attempt was to inject the script via code:

```
//Request token
chrome.windows.create({url: url, type:"popup"}, function(win){
        chrome.tabs.executeScript(win.id, { code: "console.log('Script injected!!')" }, function(){
            console.log("Callback executeScript!!");    
        });
    });
```

But the error was the same as above

Comment: What happens if you try to replace the `win.id` with `null` in the executeScript method call?  `chrome.tabs.executeScript` expects a tab id (which might be different from the window id?), also if `null` is used it will just execute in the current selected tab.

Comment: But my goal is not to run in the current tab, but on the tab that opened this window.

But since I discovered the error: I have to pass the id the Tab id and not the window id: `chrome.tabs.executeScript(win.tab[0].windowId ....`

Comment: Have u checked the permission for the script ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure whether you are wanting to inject the script into the tab opening the window, or the new tab you just opened. In any event, I made an effort to answer both questions below. First, please note that you should not attempt to load the script into the window object. The window can contain multiple tabs, and each tab has their own scripting environment. Inject your script into a tab of the newly opened window.

**Outcome 1:** Injecting the Script into the tab you Just Opened

The code below should load the script into all of the tabs of a window since `win.tabs` gives an array of tabs. For a newly opened window, there is usually only one tab.

```
chrome.windows.create({url: "https://google.com", type:"popup"}, function(win){
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(win.id.tabs, 
                              { code: "console.log('new tab context');" });
});
```

**Outcome 2:** Injecting the Script into the tab opening the window

Record the id of the tab opening the new window, then inject the script on the callback

```
var openingTabId = ASSIGN_THE_TAB_ID;
chrome.windows.create({url: "https://google.com", type:"popup"}, function(win){
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(openingTabId, 
                              { code: "console.log('opening tab context');" });
});
```

Notice that I used the `code` object to pass code without using a script file.